# ALAuthorizationStatus and handling the user's response to privacy pop-up

Tags: iphone, ios6, alassetslibrary

[Novice developer, first time posting]

I have an iOS 6 app where the first ViewController needs acces to the user's photo library. I've seen a small number of postings on how to test for access [using ALAuthorizationStatus], which I'm able to evaluate successfully, e.g., if permission is subsequently revoked by the user.

However, the problem I'm having is with the initial processing of the privacy popup [AppName Would Like to Access Your Photos]. When the app is run for the first time and before the user has clicked Ok or Don't Allow, the test [currently in ViewDidLoad in the ViewController which renders the Camera Roll in a CollectionView] has already evaluated and fails.

My working assumption is that it's because ALAssetsLibrary access is implemented via blocks, on another thread, but I haven't been able to figure out the handling of the popup that effects the privacy setting for Photos for the app.

I've tried putting a call to access the library in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572220/ask-permission-to-access-camera-roll/13572568#13572568) question, which talks about triggering the privacy setting, but to no avail.

What I need to do - I think! - is to be able to handle the setting of the privacy in a synchronous manner, but I don't know where to start with that one.

Pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: This site describes the problem I've been having: http://death-mountain.com/2011/05/alassetslibrary-and-threads/ .

Answer (score 0):

Solved through the solution offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257250/alassetslibrary-enumerategroupswithtypes-thread-synchronization) question. With my implementation, without the correct use of locking, in the event of the user being required to authorise access the enumeration of the asset library was failing. A symptom of was the user then being asked after pressing the home button.